# reading data from specified location

Tags: python

```
import CSV

#Get high temperatures from file.
filename = 'sitka_weather_07-2014.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)

    highs = []
    for row in reader:
        highs.append(row[1])

    print(highs)
```

I encountered the code above when I am learning about extract and reading data.

I didn’t quite get  the usage of next():

```
header_row = next(reader)
```

The book explains that because we have already read the header row,the loop will begins at the second line where the actual data begins

What to do if we need to read from the third line? Is the following right?

```
with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        header_row = next(reader)
        row_1 = next(reader)

        highs = []
        for row in reader:
            highs.append(row[2])

        Print(highs)
```

The question might be frivolous, but I’m very confused

Comment: I do not see why it should not. Have you tested it?

Answer (score 1):

The next function moves the cursor one row ahead, so yes in the code segment

```
header_row = next(reader)
row_1 = next(reader)
highs = []
for row in reader:
    highs.append(row[2])
Print(highs)
```

The line does start from the third line though it's not the best way to do it.

If you want to access rows directly try this instead

```
with open(filename) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    rows = list(reader)
    print rows[2]  # this will get you the third row
```